# Showing a Picture in Django Action Stream

Tags: django

I want an action stream notifications each time a user uploads a picture. I get the usual "*Actor* uploaded a *photo* on *datetime*", but I can't figure out how to add the actual picture.

I think it should be an *action_object*, but I can't get the right iteration to show the actual picture. `Photo.objects.get(pk=target)` might work, but I can't render it outside the template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone searching, I solved this with a template filter:

myapp/templatetags/myapp_tags

```
@register.filter
def get_pic(value):
    value = Photo.objects.get(pk=value).photo.url
    return value
```

template.html

```
{% for event in stream %}
    <div class="front w3-image">
     <img src="{{ event.target_object_id|get_pic }}" class="w3-image" style="height:inherit" >
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps someone